# Somas e Reformatação do db para um DataGridView

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, datagridview

Provalvemente não elaborei um titulo correto, mas vou tentar explicar minha dúvida bem detalhada.

Estou trabalhando com WindowsForm no VisualBasic15
Preciso fazer um `form` onde eu consiga dados a partir de uma `tb` em um `db`. Porém não quero apenas buscar os dados e jogar em um `DataGridView`. Gostaria que esses dados sofressem uma formatação :

Ex:

Estes são os dados salvos no meu `db`.
Clientes e Valores.

> ```
> +-----------+------+
> |  Cliente  | Val1 | 
> +-----------+------+
> | 0000000-1 | 500  | 
> | 0000000-2 | 650  | 
> | 0000000-3 | 700  |  
> | 0000000-2 | 320  |  
> | 0000000-2 | 200  | 
> | 0000000-3 | 580  | 
> +-----------+------+
> ```

Gostaria de buscar todos estes dados, porém jogando em um `DataGridView` da seguinte forma :

> ```
> +-----------+------+
> |  Cliente  | Val1 | 
> +-----------+------+
> | 0000000-1 | 500  | 
> | 0000000-2 | 1170 | 
> | 0000000-3 | 1280 |  
> +-----------+------+
> ```

De forma que eu consiga exibir as somas de todos os `Val1` referente ao respectivo Cliente e jogasse o resultado da soma dentro de 1 `Cell`

Comment: `C#` ou `Vb.Net`? Tem algum código? se sim coloque o que já fez?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Estou usando C#. Não tenho codigo pra esse `form`ainda, na verdade não sei nem por onde começar pra fazer essa execução.

Comment: é só fazer um `Select` com `GroupBy` e mostrar na Grid. Esses Valores estão em quantas tabelas, e se puder informar o nome da tabela seria bom

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Opa, Os valores estão em apenas 1 table, chamada `tbVendas` onde eu concentro todas as minhas vendas informando em uma `column` o Cliente e em outra `column`o Valor da venda; sendo cada `row`uma venda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Basicamente:***

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable(); //DataTable

string strConection = ""; // informe a string de conexao

using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection db = 
               new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(strConection))
using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand command = db.CreateCommand())
{
    db.Open(); // abre a conexão com o banco
    command.CommandText = 
                     "SELECT cliente, sum(valor) as total FROM tbVendas GROUP BY cliente";
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader()); // carrega o DataTable

    db.Close(); //Fecha a conexão.
}

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt; // carrega a grid
```

Pode ser feito com classes também, mas, acredito que a sua dúvida isso já basta.

Comment: Funcionou Perfeitamente ! Obrigado.